# How to tell a prospective employer they should rush their process because I might get another offer?

Tags: interviewing, recruiting

So I am currently unemployed and having interviews and conversations with various companies. There is one company A for which I passed various rounds of interviews, and is very likely - not sure, of course - they will make me an offer within the next few days. Again, this is not sure, but this question is in case that offer happens.

Then there is a company B, who I much prefer over  company A - but I like both, and would work at both - who is also interviewing me. The recruiting process of company B is very short in terms of number of interviews, but they set-up the interviews very very far apart.

So the situation is, the next interview with B is scheduled within two weeks, but it is likely that company A will offer me a position.

**Question**: How could I tell B in a polite, considerate but clear way, I MIGHT not be able to wait two weeks for the next interview since I might get an offer earlier? And I cannot make company A wait one month for me to decide, I'd consider that a bit too long.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I've had this scenario occur previously - the best course IMO is to be honest and upfront:

"I like this company and I would prefer to work here - but I do have an offer on the table that I've agreed to give my answer by X date - Can we push the interview forward?"

If they like you or you are a front-running Candidate they will accomodate (which happened to me) - if you aren't or they don't - then they will stick with their time frame and you go with the offer in hand.